# How to process EMR_FORCEUFIMAPPING and EMR_GDICOMMENT?

Tags: fonts, emr, spool, print-spooler-api

I am converting EMF to PDF, but I went into a problematic field. I have some EMF spool files, which contain some undocumented EMR structures such as  `EMR_FORCEUFIMAPPING` and `EMR_GDICOMMENT`.

The MSDN is not so descriptive about these records, so searching these keywords didn't help me to find my answers. As i know these records can help me to embed fonts into my generated PDFs. Does anyone have experience in this field? Can you recommend me some books or tutorials or source code repositories or some examples,

How to process these records?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

They are not undocumented.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230629.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162538%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  I don't know how you could translate the `EMR_FORCEUIFMAPPING` into anything meaningful in PDF, so you should probably just discard it.  The `EMR_GDICOMMENT` may contain any of several important records that Microsoft bizarrely chose to embed in comment records instead of making them separate record types.  Those are (vaguely) documented [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/5/E/95EF66AF-9026-4BB0-A41D-A4F81802D92C/%5BMS-EMFSPOOL%5D.pdf).